# Only include most frequent factors in legend in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

I am using

```
ggplot() +
geom_sf(data=world, fill= "#444444", show.legend = "FALSE")+
geom_sf(data=dis_sf,size=1,alpha=0.2)
```

But my second geom_sf which is a series of points mapped onto the world, I am trying to colour code by family (in the taxonomic sense) but with 284 families in my dataset I can't load the legend, I was wondering how I could only show the top 10 most frequent families (this part I can figure out) in the legend.

So for example, family 1 could be red, family 2 could be a blue dot. But everything from family 11-284 would all just be black.

Comment: I guess you have to set new levels like `c('family 1', 'family 2', 'family 3', ...,'others') and then set the colours manually.

Comment: Lookup the `forcats` package and read up on `fct_lump()` which allows you to lump together the least/most common factor levels into "other" either by count or percentage.